# Add a new List<object> to an already existing List<Object>

Tags: apex, custom-object, list

Is it possible to add a new list to each object in an already existing list?

```
List<MyObj__c> results = [SELECT Id, Name, Text__c FROM MyObj__c];
```

I have a second object obj2__c. I want to add this obj to each member of the list of MyObj__c. Obviously, results.add(obj2__c) won't work in this case.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is obj2__c is list of the same objects or itself a different object?

Comment: What do you mean by "add this obj to each member of the list ..."  Do you need to maintain a correspondence between a specific `MyObj__c` record and a specific `obj2__c` record?

Comment: Just declare results of type  “List<Sobject>” and you will be able to add MyObj__c and obj2__c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `addAll` instead.

> addAll(fromList)
>   Adds all of the elements in the specified list to the list that calls the method. Both lists must be of the same type.
>
> **Signature**
>   public Void addAll(List fromList)